# Twig loop iteration

Tags: wordpress, twig

I would like to create a twig loop to cut a long list of li and div with 3 items in each loop

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="tab-link">Word 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" class="tab-link">Word 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" class="tab-link">Word 03</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">Definition of word 01</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Definition of word 02</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">Definition of word 03</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab4" class="tab-link">Word 04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5" class="tab-link">Word 05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6" class="tab-link">Word 06</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">Definition of word 04</div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab-content">Definition of word 05</div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab-content">Definition of word 06</div>
</div>
```

I wrote this :

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="list--words nostyle">
        {% for post in posts  %}
            <li><a href="#">{{post.title}}</a></li>
            {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
                </ul></div><div class="tabs"><ul class="list--words nostyle">
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to insert my 3 tab-content ?

Comment: Does `post` have a getter for each word and another getter for the definition.?

Comment: Did you see my comment Jandon?

Comment: Do you still need help on this?